# ¿Como nombrar un fichero copia que incluya el nombre del archivo introducido por teclado en Java?

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo una duda en cuanto a la sintaxis en Java.
Estoy haciendo un programa que crea un fichero lo lee y lo copia en otro fichero. El programa me funciona, pero cuando introduzco el nombre del fichero por teclado quiero que el fichero copia se llame "copia_de_nombre" y no se como pasar ese parámetro. Adjunto código.
Mil gracias de antemano y si estoy empezando en esto.

```
package ejerciciosficheros;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nombrefichero {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Introduzca texto: ");
        String l = teclado.nextLine();
        char [] linea = l.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("Nombre del fichero: ");
        String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        File fo = new File (nombre);
        File fc = new File ("copia_de_.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que te refieres a esta línea:

```
File fc = new File ("copia_de_.txt");
```

Si quieres que se llame `copia_de_`  + el valor de `nombre`, puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

**Concatenando directamente**:

```
File fc = new File ("copia_de_"+nombre+".txt");
```

**Con `String.format()`**:

```
File fc = new File ( String.format("copia_de_%s.txt",nombre) );
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias era eso!! Lo estaba haciendo sin añadir el ultimo "+" en la primera respuesta y tambien lo puse como en la segunda respuesta pero sin añadir String.format
Leccion aprendida!! De verdad mil gracias.

Comment: @Gold considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si con esto se resuelve tu problema. Así la pregunta no queda como sin resolver y podría servir a futuros usuarios. Me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.